# How to open cyrillic domain in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I try to open cyrillic url in UIWebView, but it's can open.
I use the following code%

```
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

If i try to open https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=президент#newwindow=1&q=президент everything is OK, but when I try to open президент.рф it's doesn't work.
What I need to do for open cyrillic domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to IDN (international domain name) URLs, you need to encode them in Punycode. For example, this URL would be encoded as http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai.

Unfortunately I don't know of any built-in punycode support in iOS. But there are third-party tools like [NSURL-IDN](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/NSURL-IDN) (which is extracted from the [OmniNetworking](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniNetworking) library).